# Mysql search multiple tables and limit to 1

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:

Artists:

```
id  name
1   Band
2   DJ
```

Genres:

```
id  artist_id  genre_id
1   1          2
2   1          3
3   2          2
```

Categories:

```
id  artist_id  category_id
1   1          1
2   1          2
3   2          3
```

Prices:

```
id  artist_id  price  time
1   1          120    60
1   1          400    240
```

What I need is to use a keyword for searching in the name with a genre and category. And i need the lowest price.

So when I request this:

keyword: "band"
category: "1"
genre: "2"

the result should be:

```
Band  120
```

It should also ordered by name or by price.

I have this right now, but it returns multiple artists when they have multiple categories or genres.

```
SELECT * FROM artists
           LEFT JOIN artists_genres ON artists_genres.artist_id = artists.id 
           LEFT JOIN artists_categories ON artists_categories.artist_id = artists.id 
           LEFT JOIN artists_prices ON artists_prices.artist_id = artists.id 
           WHERE genre_id = $genre AND category_id = $cat AND name LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Group By`:

```
SELECT * FROM artists
LEFT JOIN artists_genres ON artists_genres.artist_id = artists.id 
LEFT JOIN artists_categories ON artists_categories.artist_id = artists.id 
LEFT JOIN artists_prices ON artists_prices.artist_id = artists.id 
WHERE genre_id = $genre AND category_id = $cat AND name LIKE '%$keyword%'
GROUP BY artists.artists_id
```

Comment: The problem i have now that it returns 3x a field called "id". when fetching only the last one is fetched, but i need the id of the artist.

Comment: got it, fixed it by only selecting the items I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,price FROM artists
           LEFT JOIN artists_genres ON artists_genres.artist_id = artists.id 
           LEFT JOIN artists_categories ON artists_categories.artist_id = artists.id 
           LEFT JOIN artists_prices ON artists_prices.artist_id = artists.id 
           WHERE genre_id = $genre AND category_id = $cat AND name LIKE '%$keyword%'
    GROUP BY artists_genres.artist_id ORDER BY name;
```

This will of course omit certain categories and genres but may be good enough for your needs

Answer (score 0):

You need the function MIN and have to do a GROUP BY artists.id:

```
SELECT MIN(artists_prices.price) as lowest_price * FROM artists
       LEFT JOIN artists_genres ON artists_genres.artist_id = artists.id 
       LEFT JOIN artists_categories ON artists_categories.artist_id = artists.id 
       LEFT JOIN artists_prices ON artists_prices.artist_id = artists.id 
       WHERE genre_id = $genre AND category_id = $cat AND name LIKE '%$keyword%'
GROUP BY artists.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use order and limit to obtain only one record:

```
SELECT name,artists_prices.price FROM artists
LEFT JOIN artists_genres ON artists_genres.artist_id = artists.id 
LEFT JOIN artists_categories ON artists_categories.artist_id = artists.id 
LEFT JOIN artists_prices ON artists_prices.artist_id = artists.id 
WHERE genre_id = $genre AND category_id = $cat AND name LIKE '%$keyword%'
ORDER BY artists_prices.price DESC
LIMIT 1
```